# Check if result comes from specific table in SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a search-function on my website. It searches my database for a movie, song or book, all these 3 are in different tables.
Now say that I want the SearchResult.aspx to be different for each table. For example movie is displayed in a list, song in a gridview and book in a label.

To do this I'd have to know which table the result comes from when I'm setting upp my page using C#. Can this be done?

EDIT: Search is a string entered by the user. A normal search-texbox as the one here on stackoverflow:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSearch" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Search" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

What Im thinking:

```
if(search is from tableMovies){
DisplayMovieList();
}
else if(search is from tableSongs){
DisplaySongs();
}
else{
DisplayBook();
}
```

Maybe there is a different way to do this that I'm not thinking of, it must be possible right? since for example imdb lets you search for actor and movie using the same search-box and the same searchResult-page.

My code for sending search-value:

```
Response.Redirect("SearchResult.aspx?Result=" + TextBoxSearch.Text);
```

EDIT: Working solution with the help from Tim Schmelters answer:

SQL:

```
SELECT Table1.Col1, 'Table1' As Type FROM Table1 WHERE (Table1.ColId=@param)
UNION ALL
SELECT Table2.Col2, 'Table2' As Type FROM Table2 WHERE (Table2.ColId=@param);
```

C#:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   if (reader.Read())
   {
      Label1.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Type"));
   }
}
```

The above gives me the type. Now I can just use the type to construct a few if-statements where I hide/show servercontrols depending on what table the result comes from, thanks for pointing me in the right direction Tim :)

Comment: what's search? a list of something or a string?

Comment: Sorry, Ill edit and explain

Comment: iQue, you can set the parameters while giving a redirect & on page load hide/un-hide the controls. Same you can achieve through session if you do not want to send values through the URL

Comment: By the way, you have tagged `MySql` but you use a `SqlConnection` so MS-SQL-Server.

Comment: My bad. @TimSchmelter I posted a working solution now :) Took a while but finally found what I needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little bit abstract since you haven't shown your query, but i guess you could do this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT Col1, Col2, 'Movie' As Type
    FROM dbo.Movie
    WHERE ....

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Col1, Col2, 'Book' As Type
    FROM dbo.Book
    WHERE ....

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Col1, Col2, 'Song' As Type
    FROM dbo.Song
    WHERE ....
) x
ORDER BY Col1, Col2, Type
```

Now you have the `Type` and you can use  an `if` or `switch`.

Comment: Thank you :) Could you write an example of how the if-statement would look using type like this? never used it.

Comment: What don't you understand? Use a `MySqlDataReader` and loop all records, use `reader.GetString(2)` to get the types.

Comment: If you have time, please look at my edit. Im testing right now and just trying to set label text to the type. However this does not work. "can't convert reader(ValueFromDatabase) to int"

Comment: @iQue: i don't understand what you're trying to achieve. You have a single label but you want to diplay all records there? I also don't know why you get that error since `reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Type"))` should work. Does the sql query work, have you tested it in DB?

Comment: I was just trying to see if the query worked using a label. Thats all I wanted to achieve atm. Later Ill be binding it to a listview to display all results. Ill keep testing I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Well the way i would approach this is to look up the searchstring in all tables and provide a section on the page for each result ordered by the count of found entries. I think its the common way to do that from my experiance.

I know it's a vague answer but it's also a vague question.